# Why is android saying no column when i have a column?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have this database code:

```
 public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_FNAME = "fname";
public static final String KEY_LNAME = "lname";
public static final String KEY_MNAME = "mname";
public static final String KEY_CONTACTNUM = "contactNum";
public static final String KEY_LICENSE = "license";
public static final String KEY_USER = "username";
public static final String KEY_PASS = "password";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sampleForFinals";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "drivers";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DBHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
                KEY_ROWID + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_FNAME + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_LNAME + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_MNAME + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_CONTACTNUM + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_LICENSE + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_USER + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_PASS + "TEXT NOT NULL);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + DATABASE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public DatabaseHelper(Context c) {
    ourContext = c;
}

public DatabaseHelper open() {
    ourHelper = new DBHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;

}

public void close() {
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long savedata(String fname, String lname, String mname, String contactNum, String license, String user, String pass) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_FNAME, fname);
    cv.put(KEY_LNAME, lname);
    cv.put(KEY_MNAME, mname);
    cv.put(KEY_CONTACTNUM, contactNum);
    cv.put(KEY_LICENSE, license);
    cv.put(KEY_USER, user);
    cv.put(KEY_PASS, pass);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
```

Here is my register.java

```
 register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
                String fname = firstname.getText().toString();
                String lname = lastname.getText().toString();
                String mname = middlename.getText().toString();
                String contact = contactNum.getText().toString();
                String plate = license.getText().toString();
                String user = username.getText().toString();
                String pass = password.getText().toString();

                DatabaseHelper save = new DatabaseHelper(Register.this);
                save.open();
                save.savedata(fname,lname, mname, contact, plate, user, pass);

                firstname.setText("");
                lastname.setText("");
                middlename.setText("");
                contactNum.setText("");
                license.setText("");
                username.setText("");
                password.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Basically, what the error says is:

```
table drivers has no column named mname
inserting mname=a username=a lname=a license=a password=a contactNum=4 fname=a
                                                                               android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table drivers has no column named mname (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO drivers(mname,username,lname,license,password,contactNum,fname) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

So, the database i use is from FITACADEMY. It is an sqlite. I can see the database tables and the columns and yes mname column does exist in FITACADEMY. I can see it. However, the error says it doesnt have the column 'mname'. I tried to delete all the codes related to 'mname' and it proceeds to 'user' not having a column. So, i removed all the codes related to 'user', then it has an error again of not having the column 'fname'.
Note: This is inserting data into the database.

What is wrong with my code? Ive been finding the error for 3 hours now. I still cant figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have whitespace in your `CREATE TABLE` SQL between column names and their types. For example:

```
KEY_MNAME + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
```

needs to be

```
KEY_MNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
```

Same problem with all other columns. After updating the SQL, uninstall your app to make `onCreate()` execute again.

Comment: Did you also see the "uninstall" part? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run

Comment: Do you have more than one `SQLiteOpenHelper` operating on the same database file? (Hint: Don't. See the link in my previous comment for explanation for that one, too.)

Comment: no i only have one. Also, i have to tell you that, when i tried to uninstall it and build again. I click the button to insert the data however, it doesnt say any error anymore but the logcat keeps on running like its on a loop indicating "process incoming, handlepacket, sendBufferedRequest"

Comment: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40001AB4, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
03-14 01:13:42.448 2661-2669/com.lorraine.lizzie.getaxi_driver D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
03-14 01:13:42.949 2661-2669/com.lorraine.lizzie.getaxi_driver D/jdwp: processIncoming

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your database scheme? In this case, you need to increment the database version number here:
`private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;`

Comment: increment by 1?

Comment: Yes. But I guess it doesn't matter as long as you just increment the number.

Comment: if i increment it, the app will stop and it crashes.

Comment: Can you post stacktrace of exception when it crashes?

Comment: AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "EXIST": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DROP TABLE IF EXIST sampleForFinals

Comment: Change "EXIST" to "EXISTS" in the query.

Comment: When the database version is 2. it crashes but then i add S for EXISTS. It crashes when i click on the button.

Comment: ERROR SAYS: AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table drivers already exists (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE drivers(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, fname TEXT NOT NULL, lname TEXT NOT NULL, mname TEXT NOT NULL, contactNum TEXT NOT NULL, license TEXT NOT NULL, username TEXT NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT NULL);

Comment: This is really odd. Maybe try uninstalling the app and installing again?

Comment: I already did. still not working. :(
Im crying already. Its been 4 hours now.

Comment: You also need to close "ourDatabase" variable. Use .close() method.

Comment: I am also not sure, but my databases in apps have names like "ERate.db", so I have .db in the end. Maybe that would also help.

Comment: where should i put ourDatabase.close(); ?

Comment: On your main activity's onDestroy(), I guess? I am not really good with it either, but that's where I have it.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error on your creating table query so i have correct your query try this

```
" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "( " +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_FNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_LNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_MNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_CONTACTNUM + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_LICENSE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_USER + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_PASS + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
```

Increment DB version by 1.
Enjoy :)

And one more thing onUpgrade method your dropping Database instead you should drop table:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + DATABASE_TABLE);
```

Comment: that is exactly the code i revised a minute ago. still not working :(

Comment: if i increment db, it crashes

Comment: onUpgrade instead Database Name put table name on query and please attach crash report coz its working fine with me

Comment: when i dont increment and i copied your query above. it will not crash but at the same time, it doesnt insert a record from user input into the database.

Comment: and the logcat is in a loop.

Comment: processIncoming
handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40002066, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
processIncoming
handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40002067, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
processIncoming

Comment: can you put your code on bitbucket and you can email me so that i can see the problem.